# MKDirectionsResponse returns nil always

Tags: ios7, routes, mkmapview, mapkit

I apologizes if this question is repeated but i had hard time trying to display route between two places using MKDirectionsRequest.

```
MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
    request.source = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
    request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportTypeAny;
    request.destination = _dstItem;
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = YES;


    MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
   // __block typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {

         //stop loading animation here

         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Error is %@",error);
         } else {
             //do something about the response, like draw it on map
             MKRoute *route = [response.routes firstObject];
             [self.mapView addOverlay:route.polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
         }
     }];
```

MKDirectionsResponse alway returns nil with error description

```
Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=5 "Directions Not Available" 
UserInfo=0x1700f1c80 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=A route to the nearest road cannot be determined., 
MKErrorGEOError=-403, MKDirectionsErrorCode=6, NSLocalizedDescription=Directions Not Available}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=5 "Directions Not Available"
```

You are most likely to get this error if the location doesn't belong to any of the countries in this list: http://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#maps-directions

While on iOS simulator, you can easily customize your current location. Two ways to do it:

- iOS Simulator -> 'Debug' tab -> Location -> {Choose}
- Xcode -> 'Debug' tab -> Simulate Location -> {Choose}

Answer (score 4):

MKDirectionsRequest is the right api to find route between two points. It seems Apple has not added route feature for India yet.

Answer (score 0):

i am getting same error message .if you are providing lat long of india it will not work because apple has not added rout feature for india yet try with different lat long hope it will work.i tried same and it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same Error. I still do not know the best solution yet. But I created one button on map with refresh and called the method i was calling from viewDidLoad() as I figured, my method is returning immediately with error before even calculating the address from viewDidLoad(). 
My guess is, viewDidLoad() should get finished in some specific predefined time.

So,

```
<hr/> `-(IBAction)refreshRoute:(id)sender {
         [self routeCalculate];
    }`
<hr/>
```

instead of

```
<hr/>

    -(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    [_manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [_manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

    _manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    _manager.distanceFilter =kCLDistanceFilterNone;

    [_manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [_manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [_manager startUpdatingLocation];

    [_manager delegate];
    self.pinMap.delegate = self;
    //   [self routeCalculate]; ***** This Call ****
    }

<hr/>
```